# Excel macro to border cells within variable range

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I need to automate the formating of an exported excel worksheet with variable rows and variable columns. It seems so simple but I am stumped. I just need to add borders to all cells in the table.

I'm not terribly confident with VBA but have been searching for a solution to this for a few days with no luck. Plenty of help for fixed ranges, and managed to achieve what I need for a single column but I've hit a wall and can't seem to get the whole range to work.

Example of what I'm trying to do in english:

Add borders to cells in range "A1" to "last column with data in row 1 and last row with data in column A"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub BoxIt()
Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    With r.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With r.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First comment was incorrect - deleted it. This code is perfect, thank you GS. Is there a way to skip rows based on values?

Comment: Row contains "abc" or "def" in Column A.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary's Student. I will post another question for the next step as it is a different topic anyway. Your solution is exactly what I needed and works a treat.