# Excel macro to format dynamic range with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I previously asked for help to get the code to format a variable range and [Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student) was able to provide me with a fantastic solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20920895/3159818).

I now realise that I need the formating to be conditional based on Column A values and I'm a bit stumped again and my original question doesn't invite a solution to this problem.

I have now got code to apply borders to every cell in my variable sized table but I'd like to be able to leave rows without borders based on the value of the first cell in column A.

For example:
If the first cell in A contains "abc", skip formatting.
or
If first cell in column A does not contain "abc" apply formatting.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Gary's Students Code:

```
Sub BoxIt()
Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
With r.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With r.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With r.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With r.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With r.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With r.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
End Sub'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (this code adds new CF to current region of `A1` range and applies formatting when row in column `A` *doesn't contains* string from `StrToFind` variable):

```
Sub test()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim StrToFind As String

   StrToFind = "abc"
   Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
   With r
       .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=ISERROR(FIND(""" & StrToFind & """,$A1))"
       .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

       With .FormatConditions(1)
           With .Borders(xlLeft)
               .LineStyle = xlContinuous
               .ColorIndex = 0
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .Weight = xlThin
           End With
           With .Borders(xlTop)
               .LineStyle = xlContinuous
               .ColorIndex = 0
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .Weight = xlThin
           End With
           With .Borders(xlBottom)
               .LineStyle = xlContinuous
               .ColorIndex = 0
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .Weight = xlThin
           End With
           With .Borders(xlRight)
               .LineStyle = xlContinuous
               .ColorIndex = 0
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .Weight = xlThin
           End With

           .StopIfTrue = False
       End With

   End With

End Sub
```

Some notes:

1) depending on your local settings formula `"=ISERROR(FIND(""" & StrToFind & """,$A1))"` may be wrong, in that case you should use `"=ISERROR(FIND(""" & StrToFind & """;$A1))"` (look at seperators in formula just before `$A1`: it is either a comma or a semicolon).

2) you should call this function each time your table has changed size

3) the 'normal' format of your table should be without borders (borders will appears with help of CF only in case when row in column `A` *doesn't contains* `abc`)

Hope it helps!

Comment: No access to my computer at the moment but very excited to try your code simoco. Will this work with multiple strings? (Eg. "abc" or "def"). Thank you very much for your detailed reply. I will let you know how I get on as soon as I've tried it.

Comment: Sure, it will works, but you should to modifu formula. Something like this should work: `"=AND(ISERROR(FIND(""" & StrToFind & """,$A1)), ISERROR(FIND(""" & AnotherStrToFind & """,$A1)))"` - this formula will trigger CF only in case when row in column A doesn't conatains both `StrToFind` and `AnotherStrToFind `

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get this code to work. I played around with it for quite a while but have had no luck. I have managed a rather ugly work around with the recorder that should suit most of what I need. Thanks heaps for your quick and detailed solution simoco.